# Windows 7 BSOD on hybernate

Tags: windows, bsod

Sometimes I experience a BSOD when my laptop goes to hybernate. It happends all the way on the end of the hybernation cycle, so the laptop is actually off, harddisk spins down, lights and screen are out, but then after a few seconds I get a BSOD.

Trouble is that it does not happen all the time, maybe 1 out of 5 times, but I cannot find the reason why.

The event log does not give me any real information, just this error:
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck. The bugcheck was: 0x0000009f (0x00000003, 0x866f7030, 0x83172ae0, 0x8aaa6658). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 020510-29203-01.

I get this errors:
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID: 1043
Additional information about the problem:
BCCode: 9f
BCP1: 00000003
BCP2: 866FAB60
BCP3: 83127AE0
BCP4: 8AAFF098
OS Version: 6_1_7600
Service Pack: 0_0
Product: 256_1
Files that help describe the problem:
C:\Windows\Minidump\020710-21902-01.dmp
C:\Users\Rogier\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-45084-0.sysdata.xml

http://www.xs4all.nl/~cpvers/WER-45084-0.sysdata.xml

http://www.xs4all.nl/~cpvers/020710-21902-01.dmp

I have tried to check out these dmp files, but I am not certain what I should look for.

If somebody can tell me what I should look for in these dump files, so I can go forward with this :)

I have all the latest official drivers for 7 and no strange drivers, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: Belongs at http://superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0x9f is DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE.

0x3 as the first parameter means "A device object has been blocking an IRP for too long a time."

It looks like one of your drivers is buggy.